# MapMyFitness API OAuth questions

Tags: ios, api, oauth, mapmyfitness

I am having some issues with MapMyFitness API. MapMyFitness uses OAuth 1.0

I am able to successfully get a temporary Authorization token/temporary secret Token combination from calling 3.1/oauth/request_token

After that, I am able to successfully direct the user to the Authorization page and get a redirect callback with a authorization verifier.

After that, I am, unfortunately, getting errors when trying to call 3.1/oauth/access_token. (HTTP error 401)

First of all, MMF documentation (http://api.mapmyfitness.com/3.1/oauth/access_token?doc) states: Exchange a request token and an authorization verifier for an access token. However, the list of input arguments in the documentation contains no mention of oauth_verifier.  Should oauth_verifier that I have received with the redirect callback be passed to access_token call as an argument?

Secondly, it appears to me that perhaps I am not creating the signature correctly. For the 3.1/oauth/request_token call the key to generate the signature is 'XXX&' where XXX is the Consumer Secret Key assigned to my app by MapMyFitness. This works fine. For the 3.1/oauth/access_token call, I am using 'XXX&YYY' as a signature key where XXX is the Consumer Secret Key assigned to my app by MapMyFitness and YYY is the temporary Secret Token returned to me by the server during the 3.1/oauth/request_token call. Is that correct?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working. First of all, oauth_verifier DOES need to be included as part of parameters. For some reason, Map My Fitness does not include it in its list of required parameters, but it has to be there. Secondly - very important - according to OAuth 1.0 documentation, all parameters need to be in alphabetical order when creating the signature - otherwise there will be a signature mismatch and you'll get HTTP 401 error. Once I sorted my parameters in alphabetical order, I was able to exchange temporary MapMyFitness credentials to permanent ones.